# Laravel Mix compiling js and css in the js directory incorrectly

Tags: laravel-8, bootstrap-5, laravel-mix

I have the following in (webpack.mix.js)

```js
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

after running **npm run dev**, my css and js files are compiled in the js directory and the css directory is not created.

it should be:
**/public/js/app.js** and **/public/css/app.css**

but ends up being:
**/public/js/app.js** and **/public/js/app.css**

even if i try to only add the css line in (webpack.mix.js)

it then creates mix.css

any reason why this does not work?

package.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.2",
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^5.0.0",
        "sass": "^1.49.9",
        "sass-loader": "^12.6.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I just had the exact same problem after a brand new clone of my project. My issue was that I cloned my project under a directory that contained a **#** (so it was higher in the explorer).

The path of my project was something like `c:\dev\#laravelprojects\myproject`

Removing this **#** from the directory name solved the problem and my css now compiles in the `public/css` directory.

Maybe you also got a path issue.